# MSI Laptop integrated camera driver shows "USB Boot" as name and doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam

As the title suggests, my laptop's integrated camera has stopped working. It currently shows "USB Boot" as the name of the driver and is shown in applications, however, it doesn't actually function at all.

I have tried uninstalling the driver, looking (and failing to find) the drivers from the official manufacturer's website, I have already pressed fn+f6 to try and turn it off and on again and it didn't work.

My laptop is an MSI gp62 7RD Leopard. Unfortunately, I don't have any system restore points either because it is for some reason turned off by default.

Any help is much appreciated considering skyping and using discord video is impossible due to this issue and I don't have an alternative other than using my phone for hours on end.

[Device in Device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzKgk.png)

[Trying to use the webcam in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oryD3.png)

[Device Hardware ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPGiQ.png)

Comment: What happens if you press Function & F6 at the same time on the keyboard?

Comment: Also, under device manager/driver tab can you give me the Hardware ID from the pull-down menu?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: I have tried pressing Function f6 and it did not work, and I have updated the post with the Hardware ID